# How to know if CPU fan is ending his life?

Tags: cpu, temperature, fan

I have laptop Dell Inspiron 15 5570 (I'm not using GPU only build in Intel graphic card) and have this issue:

I have this output from dmesg:

```
[170178.959009] CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3635)
[170178.959010] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3635)
[170178.959031] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4393)
[170178.959032] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4391)
[170178.959034] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4392)
[170178.959035] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4393)
[170178.959036] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4393)
[170178.959038] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4393)
[170178.959039] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4393)
[170178.959045] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4393)
```

it shows multiple times, when I've run `sensors` it shows:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:    0 RPM
CPU:            +52.0°C  
Ambient:        +45.0°C  
SODIMM:         +45.0°C  
GPU:            +30.0°C  

amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:           N/A  
fan1:             N/A  (min =    0 RPM, max =    0 RPM)
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +104000.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:           N/A  (cap =  37.00 W)
```

Fedora that I'm using have issue with claws-mail + libnotify that consume 100% (1 out of 4 CPU and 8 Threads), when this happen this is the output from sensors:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +75.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +75.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 2721 RPM
CPU:            +65.0°C  
Ambient:        +49.0°C  
SODIMM:         +42.0°C  
GPU:            +30.0°C  

amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:           N/A  
fan1:             N/A  (min =    0 RPM, max =    0 RPM)
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +104000.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:           N/A  (cap =  37.00 W)
```

Should I do something with this dmesg error and send the laptop to fix the fan (it's still on warranty)? What should I say about my laptop? Should I wait until fan stops working (show 0 RPM when one of the CPU is 100%)?

Comment: being a laptop, and a dell, i would expect some sort of conclusive proof at the BIOS level showing a fan problem.  That said go into BIOS and make sure fan settings are on high speed max cooling, no energy saver stuff.  And then being a laptop it could be other things than the fan like placement of laptop on plush blanket or carpet which will prevent airflow, as well as dust/dirt within laptop.

Comment: Dell devices normally have a built in diagnostics check that you can access through the BIOS (normally by pressing F12 on boot).  This should check your fans and throw an error if there is a problem.  Generally Dell will want you to run this before returning faulty hardware anyway.

Comment: How many system admins/devs does it take to change a light bulb? None - that’s a hardware problem. Might be better of on asking on a different site.